# Prove $ 1+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)+...+\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{n}{x}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

Prove:

$$ 1+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)+...+\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{n}{x}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right)$$

The first part could be rewritten as a series such as:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

Maybe it could be transform into a Taylor series, but I just don't know where to start.

Comment: It's a finite geometric series: $1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$.

Comment: The form of series you write in sigma is different from the first summation. $n$ is constant? or ...

Comment: In the sigma, you write $n$ can not start from zero, because of division by zero

Comment: @Khosrotash I think it's $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{x}{n})^i$

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sum of terms in geometric progression, mimicking its proof write
\begin{align}
S&=1+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)+...+\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}\\
S\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)&=\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)+\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{2}+...+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n
\end{align}
then subtract second equality from first to get
$$
S\frac{x}{n}=1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n
$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^i=\frac{1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}{1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)}=\frac{n}{x}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

take $q=1-\frac xn$

you may now $s_n=1+q+q^2+q^3+...+q^{n-1}=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$

now put $q=1-\frac xn$
  so $$1+\left( 1-\frac{x}{n}\right)+...+\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}= \\ 1+q+q^2+...+q^{n-1}\\ \to \frac{1-q^n}{1-q}=\frac{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})^n}{1-(1-\frac{x}{n})}$$